# C++ static member function as C callback needs to access non static reference

Tags: c++, c, static, callback, extern

In my C++ code I have a dependecy on a C library. This C library lets me define a callback with 3 arguments. Example:

file.c:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
     typedef void(*callback)(argument* 1, argument* 2, argument* 3);
...
     void set_callback(ARG1, callback name_of_callback);
...
```

In the C++ library i'm developing i want this callback to be a member function of a class, since I cannot pass directly a member function as the callback to the C library I created a static function to be the callback and inside this static function I want to have a reference to a class object and call its member function to do the work.

Now my problem is that my static functions needs to have the 3 arguments specified by the C library, so i'm not finding a way of having a reference to an object of the class i'm developing inside that static function. Example of I wanted to do:

MyClass.h:

```
class MyClass:
public:
   MyClass();
   void my_function(argument*1, argument* 2, argument* 3);
   static void my_callback(argument* 1, argument* 2, argument*3);
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
MyClass::MyClass(){
    set_callback(ARG1, my_callback);
}

void MyClass::my_function(argument*1, argument* 2, argument* 3){ 
      /* Do something */}
void MyClass::my_callback(argument* 1, argument* 2, argument*3){
    Object->my_function(1, 2, 3);
}
```

The reason to not set the class members as static is that i want to be able to create and destroy objects of this class for testing purposes and control the state of the object within the tests.

I'm using g++ and gcc, hope someone can give some help with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your `set_callback` call provides one of the arguments passed to the callback later?  Pass your `MyClass*` through that parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static member function or a pure 'C' function to do this, consider my example below:

```
/**
 * C++ part
 */
class obj
{
public:
    obj() {}
    ~obj() {}

    void doSomething(int a, int b) { cout << "result = " << a+b << endl; }
};

/**
 * C Part
 */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
{
typedef void (*callback)(void* one, void* two, void* three);

callback g_ptr = NULL;
void* arg = NULL;

void c_lib_core (void)
{
    printf ("C Lib core...\n");
    if (g_ptr)
    {
        g_ptr(arg, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

void set_callback (void* arg, callback ptr)
{
    g_ptr = ptr;
}

void my_callback (void* one, void* two, void* three)
{
    obj* my_obj = (obj*) one;

    my_obj->doSomething(1,2);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif



int main (void)
{
    obj a;

    set_callback (&a, my_callback);

    c_lib_core ();
}
```

Output:

```
C Lib core...
result = 3
```

I pass a pointer to the C++ object as argument 1. This allows the callback to cast it back to C++ and call it. The c_lib_core stuff is just so I can simulate the callback of the callback function for testing purposes. This, along with the global variables will be in the C code somewhere. You only need to implement a single C function and set ARG1 to your object and you are good to go.

Comment: I implemented the above solution using a global pointer to my object, the set_callback function and the my_callback. the set_callback funtion is called from the C++ side from the class constructor. I've been able to pass the same test under this solution and the one below. I'm just wondering regarding memory usage if this solution is better than having static functions and static members of the class? The goal is to use this code in a microcontroller with very limited resources. Thanks

Comment: Static members should take the same memory as they are defined once. They may be an entry in the vtptrs but unsure of this to be honest. If they processor is such a concern memory wise perhaps pure C is the way to go so you do not need to include both the C and C++ runtime libraries which is far more of a memory concern than a few bytes here and there

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no concurrency concerns, which i don't know if it's the case, the simpler solution could be to define an static instance and use that in your static function.

Something like this.

MyClass.h

```
class Object;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    static Object* object;
    static void callback();
    ~MyClass();

};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
Object* MyClass::object;

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    object = new Object();
}

void MyClass::callback() {
    object->sayHello();
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    delete object;
}
```

Comment: The reason to not set the class members as static is that i want to be able to create and destroy objects of this class for testing purposes and control the state of the object within the tests.

Comment: Sorry. Anyway, you still can create and destroy objects and control the state of them within tests. Why defining the class members as static prevents that ?

Comment: I want to make sure that on test1 I create a MyClass with members with one state (p.ex. object has ID=1) and that when the event happens the callback executes the member function, on test2 i want to create a MyClass where the members are on another state (object has ID=5) and the callback executes the same member function. I was under the impression that declaring object static that would forced object to a state defined at compile time.

Comment: Not at all. `static` and constant are different things. i.e, in my example `static` means that there's only one `Object` pointer **per class**, not per instance of that class. Neither the pointer nor the object pointed to are constant in any way, you can still access them. You could, i.e, pass an `ID ` to the `MyClass` constructor and use that `ID ` to instantiate the new `Object` with; then each time a new `MyClass` is created you will have a different object with different ID pointed to by `object`.